# Can you prove that $(a=b) \vdash (b=a)$ using only Fitch 'Elim' and 'Intro'?

Tags: logic

My text says

> **Proof**: Suppose that a = b. We know that a = a, by *Intro*. Now substitute the name *b* for the first use of the name *a* in *a = a*, using *Elim*. We come up with b = a, as desired.

However, earlier in the textbook, the author remarks that,

> *Elim* eliminates the identity symbol.

and that,

> *Intro* introduces the identity symbol.

I attempted to reconstruct the proof in *f* notation.

1. a=b:
2. a=a: *Intro 1*
3. a:  *Elim 2*

That didn't get me a=b.

So considering the author's definition of *Intro* and of *Elim*, I can't figure how he derived his conclusion. What do I misunderstand?

Comment: Actually, you don't need reflexivity (your Intro rule?) if you have substitutions (your Elim rule?). Suppose a=b. Substitute a for b to get a=a. Substitute b for first occurrence of a to b=a.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the rules are the following :

> Equality Introduction : $\tau = \tau$ --- $\tau$ is a *term*
>
> Equality Elimination : from $\varphi[\tau_1]$ and $\tau_1 = \tau_2$, infer $\varphi[\tau_2]$ --- $\tau_2$ substitutable for $\tau_1$ in $\varphi$.

In order to prove that :

> > $a = b \vdash b =a$

we must start from $a = a$, by Eq-intro, and then use it as $\varphi[a]$, where the first $a$ takes the place of $\tau_1$.

Using the assumption $a = b$, where $b$ takes the place of $\tau_2$, we get $\varphi[b]$, by Eq-elim.

But what is $\varphi[b]$ ? It is obtained from $a = a$ whit the left occurrence of $a$ (the $\tau_1$) replaced by $b$ (the $\tau_2$), i.e. :

> > $b = a$.

In conclusion :

> $a = b \vdash b = a$.

Answer (score 2):

Mauro gives you the proof. One added comment:

> *Elim* eliminates the identity symbol,

is a somewhat unhappy way of putting things! An elimination rule for a logical operator $O$ tells you how to argue from a proposition involving an occurrence of $O$ as its principal operator to a conclusion. But it isn't required that the conclusion doesn't also contain $O$. Thus, in Mauro's rule

> *Equality Elimination*: from φ[τ1] and τ1=τ2, infer φ[τ2] --- τ2 substitutable for τ1 in φ.

it isn't required that the context $\varphi$ have no occurrences of the identity symbol. Indeed, as Mauro shows, to derive the intended conclusion in this case, $\varphi$ will indeed involve the identity sign. And there will therefore still be an identity sign in the conclusion. But that's not a problem.

Comment: Okay, so basically - equality elimination says that anytime you have a=b, you can always substitute a for b, and vice versa. Thus, by *Elim* and a=b, we can warrant writing a=b, b=a, a=a, b=b?  But since both a=a and b=b are redundant, we can write a for a=a and b for b=b?

Comment: @Hal - about $b = b$, this is the same as $a = a$; so, you do not really need *Elim*. Axioms are *schema* : when you write *Elim* in the form $\tau_1 = \tau_2$ you license an "infinity" of instances of it : all those that you can produce from the schema "instantiating" it with a *term* of your language.

Comment: @Hal - The axiom or rule $a = a$ is **not** "redundant" at all. The single expression $a$ is a *term* i.e. a "name". The rule of a logical calculus use name to buid formulas, but inference rules and axioms are "made of" formulas. It is the same as in natural language: with only names it is quite hard to make a speech: the only thing you can do is to use them as when you utter "Fido !" in order to  retrieve your dog.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Hm. Why do you use T1 = T2 instead of a=b? Also, what does 'schema' mean?

Comment: @Hal - $\tau$ is just a variable for terms (i.e.names) : in my reference (on the web) I've found this formulation of *Eq-intro* and *Eq-elim*, so I used it. If in your textbook, terms are symbolized with the initial portion of the *latin* alphabet... it's the same thing. Schema means a "general recipy" to build up a formula : when we say that $A \rightarrow A$ is a tautology, we mean that **all** sentences we get from it substituting (e.g.) a mathematical formula in place of $A$ will be again a tautology; for example: $0 = 0 \rightarrow 0 = 0$ is a math formula that, ... 1/2

Comment: ...being an instance of the above tautology, is (trivial but) true in every language where the term $0$ is allowed. 2/2